# Methods to evaluate this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Steps to evaluate this limit?

$$\lim_{t\to 4}\frac{4-t}{\sqrt{t}-2}$$

Answer (score 3):

For $t\neq 4$, we get $$\frac{4-t}{\sqrt{t}-2}=\frac{4-t}{\sqrt{t}-2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{t}+2}{\sqrt{t}+2}=\frac{(4-t)(\sqrt{t}+2)}{(t-4)}=-(\sqrt{t}+2).$$
Then evaluate as $t\to 4$. You should get $-4$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the options:

1. $$\lim_{t\to4}\space\frac{4-t}{\sqrt{t}-2}=\lim_{t\to4}\space\frac{-1}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}}=-2\lim_{t\to4}\space\sqrt{t}\tag1$$
2. $$\lim_{t\to4}\space\frac{4-t}{\sqrt{t-2}}=\lim_{t\to4}\space\frac{-1}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t-2}}}=-2\lim_{t\to4}\space\sqrt{t-2}\tag2$$

Using l'Hôpital's rule

Answer (score 1):

$\text{ Let }  u=\sqrt{t}-2 \\\  $

So $u+2=\sqrt{t} \text{ and } (u+2)^2=t 
\\\ $

This gives us:

$\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{4-(u+2)^2}{u}$

$=-\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{(u+2)^2-4}{u}$

$=-\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{(u+2)^2-4}{u-0}$

This part next to the -1 multiple is in the form $\lim_{u \rightarrow a} \frac{f(u)-f(a)}{u-a}$.

$f(u)=(u+2)^2 \\\ $

$f(a)=4 \text{ where } a=0$

So we have the limit is $-(\frac{d}{du}(u+2)^2)|_{u=0}$